# Use Shouldjs with Bluebird to test Promises

Tags: node.js, bluebird, should.js

How do I use Shouldjs to test Promises, with Bluebird?

```
var should = require('should');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.reject().should.be.fulfilled();
> TypeError: Promise.reject(...).should.be.fulfilled is not a function
```

Bluebird 3.0.6
Should 7.1.1
Node 4.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Needed Shouldjs 8.x.

Comment: In 7.x.x need to also install `should-promised`.